# Write text file to Blob in Azure using PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to write a text file to the blob. I know i have to create a container and a blob. I need to write something like this:

```
$text = 'some text';
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file c");
fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);
```

The question is I want to write this php script but using blob ( we dont have access to the file the system ) how can I do that?

Comment: But...? Where's the question?

Comment: I want to write the same script, but it doesnt work with azure, i I dont have access to the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving the file to disk you'll need to upload it to a container:

```
_storageClient->putBlob('mycontainer', 'file.txt', 'file.txt');
```

You can do this by using the Windows Azure PHP SDK. Follow this tutorial for more information: **[Put a Blob in a Blob Container](http://www.windowsazure4e.org/learn/labs/lab2_azure_storage/lab2_1_azure_storage_blobs/#task10_1)**

Comment: but how I can write/append a text to the file?

Comment: how can i do the fwrite part? I can only provide the file path, not the content